# Under burnt layer prevention for briyani

Tags: rice, burnt, indian-cuisine

When I cook briyani on a electric stove top, how do I prevent the bottom layer of the dish in the pot from burning?

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/71521/67 ; https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/68514/67 ; https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/53776/67

Comment: @Jan : but what if Ryka wants it sticky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I start mine on the stovetop, it mainly cooks in the oven.  That might help.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @moscafj. Or you could also try placing a cast iron tawa(the cast iron dosa tawa in India) or a cast iron skillet  directly on slow fire or on the electric stove top on low-medium heat and placing the biryani pot on top of it. If you are placing the biryani pot directly on the stove, make sure you are using a heavy-bottom pot and the heat is on low-medium setting. Hope this helps.